# How many gold badges do I have?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

The summary of how many badges I have, shown in my user profile, shows three gold badges. Yet the list of badges shows four. What is the cause of this apparent discrepancy?

[image]

Comment: Excellent execution of a humble-brag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The summary section, where it says you have 3 Gold Badges, is cached and updated daily (UTC).

Comment: Yep, this is caching!